# Need Help to Edit a Landscape Output

Tags: positioning

I got confused on how to improve the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[paperheight=13in,paperwidth=8.5in,top=1in,left=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{2cm}|c|c|}
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Proponents}} & \textbf{Study} & \textbf{Date Completed/Published} & \textbf{Collaborationg Agency} \\
\hline
Berlita Y. Disca&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Programs on Drug and Substance Abuse Prevention and Law Enforcement in Two Cities in Region 12: An Empirical Study}}&   \multirow{2}[2]{*}{August 2017}&
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{DOST-PCHRD REGION 12}\\
Edgar Mabad     &           &           &\\
\hline      
Leonida, Rene E. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}[2]{*}{Secure Weakly Connected Domination in the Join of Graphs}} & \multirow{5}[2]{*}{ March  2015} & \multirow{5}[2]{*}{HIKARI Ltd.}\\
    Dela Cruz, Rendon A.        &       &       &  \\
    Aujero, Emmylou M.          &       &       &  \\
    Deleverio, Marchelle A. &       &       &  \\
    Bodegas, Nimfa L.           &       &       &  \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Compiling it I got

[image]

I don't know how to edit it. Please help.

Comment: @TeXnician Why I can't make it appeared like what you did in your edit?

Comment: You can, just use the `{}` button while having the text selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=13in,paperwidth=8.5in,top=1in,left=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXcc}
Proponents & \textbf{Study} & \textbf{Date Completed/Published} & \textbf{Collaborationg Agency} \\
\midrule
\makecell[tl]{Berlita Y. Disca \\ Edgar Mabad}  & Programs on Drug and Substance Abuse Prevention and Law Enforcement in Two Cities in Region 12: An Empirical Study & August 2017 & DOST-PCRD Region12\\ 
\midrule 
\makecell[tl]{Leonida, Rene E. \\ Dela Cruz, Rendon A. \\ Aujero, Emmylou M. \\ Deleverio, Marchelle A. \\ Bodegas, Nimfa L.}& Secure Weakly Connected Domination in the Join of Graphs &  March  2015 &HIKARI Ltd.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

I have used the package `tabularx` to be able to use its flexible width `X` column for the second column of the table. The table itself is as wide as the current linewidth. The `X` column's width is now linewidth-widht(col1)-width(col3)-width(col4) and long lines inside it are automatically broken.

In oder to achieve the formatting of the first column, I used the `makecell` package to be able to introduce linebreaks inside the cell using `\\`.

Lastly, I have used the package `booktabs` and its command `\midrule`. Additionally I have removed all vertical lines in the table, as most of the times they are not neccessery to understand the table

[image]